# Métodos estáticos X Métodos não estáticos para camada de acesso a dados

Tags: .net, ado.net

Estou criando uma camada em ADO.NET para acesso a dados e pintou uma dúvida.
É uma boa prática ter os meus métodos de acesso a dados como static ao invés de ter que sempre ficar instanciando o objeto e chamar o método?

Comment: É boa prática sim.

Comment: Não, não é não.

Comment: não, não é... se vc utilizar multiplas threads pra fazer um `update`, por exemplo.... pode dar "treta" rs

Comment: Não entendi....como que pode dar "treta"? Se o valor recebido pelo método estático vai ser o da thread, como que ele vai conseguir se perder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A verdade é que depende do "quão sofisticado" você é...

Em geral eu diria que **não**, não é uma boa prática.

Utilizando métodos estáticos no `DAO`, você não pode modificar o comportamento dele (em casos de sobrecarga, por exemplo)...

Se você utilizar 2 ou mais threads simultaneamente, se uma das threads fechar o `DAO` antes das outras, o que tem grandes chances de acontecer, você não vai ter o resultado que espera, concorda? Sem contar pra outros casos como testes unitários... é bem mais complicado... então algumas desvantagens:

- Não é **seguro** em uma aplicação *multi-thread*.
- Não pode injetar dependências em classes estáticas.
- "Dificulta" a implementação de testes unitários....

Aconselho a utilização do padrão `Singleton` para seu `DAO`:

```
public class ClienteDAO { 
  private static final ClienteDAO SINGLETON = openInst(); 

  private static ClienteDAO openInst() { 
    // Iniciar o DAO
  } 

  public ClienteDAO getInstance() { 
    return SINGLETON; 
  } 
}
```

A vantagem é que ele é seguro em aplicações multi-threads e você pode modificar o método `openInst()` em testes unitários para criar `Mocks` para o seu `DAO`, o que vai simplificar e MUITO seus testes unitários.